# excel: vba type mismatch using find

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet where:

- If the value in cell in column `I` is "Não marcou férias" then it should search the whole column `A` and find all times that the unique number for that specific person appears more than once.
- If the unique number appears twice or more and the column `I` of that row is not "Não marcou férias" then it should compare with current year and write `ATUAL` in the corresponding cell in column `K`. If it's true then the row in column `K` that have "Não marcou férias" should be blank.

Here is my sheet:

[image]

And this is what I want to happen:

[image]

As you can see as I have two entries with number `59837` and one of them is "Não marcou férias", I want it to run through column A and find if exist another entry and as it is current, it should write "ATUAL" on it.

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()

Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date

Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan1")

lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow

date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 9)
date2 = ws1.Cells(j, 12)

If ws1.Cells(j, 9) = "Não marcou férias" Then
k = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
    With ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    Set c = .Find(k, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            If ws1.Cells(j, 9) <> "Não marcou férias" Then
                If Year(date1) = Year(Date) Or Year(date2) = Year(Date) Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, 13) = "ATUAL"
                Else
                    ws1.Cells(j, 13) = ""
                End If
            End If

    Set c = .FindNext(c)

        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
DoneFinding:
    End With
End If

Next j

End Sub
```

But when I try to run I get:

> Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

And this line is highlighted:

```
date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 9)
```

My Excel is in portuguese so here we use date format like dd/mm/yyyy and all my columns are set up as dates correctly.

Is there anyone with suggestions? I don't know why I'm getting this type mismatch again since I've already applied [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904915/6088173) solution.

**EDIT:** I've tested the suggested solutions, but I still have the same problem in the same line.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test2()

Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date
Dim k As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan1")

lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow

date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 9)
date2 = ws1.Cells(j, 12)

If Not IsDate(ws1.Cells(j, 9)) Then
    k = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
    With ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    Set c = .Find(k, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            If IsDate(ws1.Cells(j, 9)) Then
                If Year(date1) = Year(Date) Or Year(date2) = Year(Date) Then
                    ws1.Cells(j, 13) = "ATUAL"
                Else
                    ws1.Cells(j, 13) = ""
                End If
            End If

    Set c = .FindNext(c)

        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
DoneFinding:
    End With
End If

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: `If ws1.Cells(j, 9) = "Não marcou férias" Then`: `ws1.Cells(j, 9)` is not a date, so `date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 9)` is of course `type mismatch` because of `Dim date1 As Date` :) . I think you should first check with `If IsDate(ws1.Cells(j, 9) )` and take that into account.

Comment: @A.S.H I really got it although I need to do this comparison in that column. I tried the Vityata's solution and Message Box appoints I6 as a date, for example. I could try to change my comparison instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Always make sure that you include `Option Explicit` on top of your code.
- Simply write `msgbox ws1.Cells(j, 9).address` on the line above the line with the error.
- Check the MsgBox coming before the error.
- I can bet a virtual beer, that the address is pointing to is a value, which is not a date. For example `I6` in your screenshot, saying something nice about vacations and booking in Portuguese.

In your code, you may add something like `If IsDate(ws1.cells(j,9)) then`. It would check whether the given value is a date or not. In your case `Não marcou férias` cannot be parsed as a `Date` format, thus you get an error. Or simply try to replace the code positions like this:

```
For j = 2 To lastrow    
   If ws1.Cells(j, 9) <> "Não marcou férias" Then
      date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 9)
      date2 = ws1.Cells(j, 12)
      k = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
      With ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
```

If the value is not "Nao marcou ferias" then its probably  a date (although, its better to use the `IsDate()`).

Have fun, TGIF

Comment: Let's see if this beer will happen! Anyway, I've tested two things: when I don't use `Option Explicit` the code runs fine and the message box appoints to `I6` also as a date. And then it gets type mismatch again. Then when I try with `Option Explicit` I get `k = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value` highlighted and variable not defined.

Comment: The idea of `Option Explicit`, is to tell you that you have forgotten to write `Dim k as Something` on the top. And in your screenshot `I6` is not a date format. And what do you mean by saying MessageBox appoints to `I6` also as a date?

Comment: Yes, yes, I'm declaring all my variables now. What I've tryed to say is that `I6` is not a date, but the whole column is formatted as a date even if there is a text on it. So I thought it would work the same way.

Comment: Well, if the whole column is formatted as a `Date`, but the value in `I6` is not a date, the VBA engine is still looking for a date, to parse into `date1` And the Portuguese string cannot be parsed to a date in any way...

Comment: Oh, now I got it. So what I've thought doesn't work. Anyway, I can't change this value. It should be `Não marcou férias` so I must change my comparison, I guess...

Comment: @paulinhax - you have plenty of options to fix it. Take a look at my edited answer, I point out 2. The `IsDate()` check is the better one.

Comment: I've seen that update now, thanks. Just another doubt, when I declare a variable with address as `firstAddress` it should be a string or a range? Because I know `.Adress` property returns a string but I get type mismatch again.

Comment: @paulinhax - in this case - String. But if you are not sure, declare it as a Variant like this `Dim firstAddress` and later see what VBA thinks it is. To do it, put a stop on the line after the variable and click `Shift + F9` It would write something like `Variant/String` in the VB Editor.

Comment: Actually, it is a String! But I've return to my first problem. I'll post my edited code.